# Can Cassandra row cache only cache on specific columns?

Tags: cassandra

I have a C* table which are wide and some columns are read-heavy. I am considering using row cache but do not know if row cache can store specific columns. If all the cells of that row need to be stored, the content to be cached may grow too fast and defeat the purpose.

The schema is like follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tb1 (
    pk1 int,
    ck1 int,
    read_heavy_col1 int,
    read_heavy_col2 int,
    normal_col1 int,
    normal_col2 int,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (pk1, ck1)
)
```

The question is if row cache is able to cache `pk1, ck1, read_heavy_col1, read_heavy_col2` only and ignores `normal_col1, normal_col2, ...`.

According to [DataStax Configuring data caches](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsConfiguringCaches.html),

> If the newly cached data does not include all cells configured by
>   user, Cassandra performs another read.

Does that mean C* can cache only the columns of interest?

Comment: How many columns do you have?

Comment: Say 20 normal columns but only 2 are regularly accessed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own questions:
Cassandra will cache all columns of that row.

From "Cassandra The Definitive Guide" (2nd edition) by Jeff Carpenter & Eben Hewitt:

> The row cache caches entire rows and can speed up read access for frequently accessed rows, at the cost of more memory usage.

Experiment:

```
abc@cqlsh:test> SELECT pk1, ck1, read_heavy_col1 FROM tb1 WHERE pk1=2 and ck1=1;

 pk1 | ck1 | read_heavy_col1
-----+-----+-----------------
   2 |   1 |               1

(1 rows)

Tracing session: 53aac630-11be-11e9-9cb3-fbffb1c1e13b

 activity                                                                                               | timestamp                  | source       | source_elapsed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------
                                                                                     Execute CQL3 query | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.667000 | x.x.x.x |              0
 Parsing SELECT pk1, ck1, read_heavy_col1 FROM tb1 WHERE pk1=2 and ck1=1; [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.668000 | x.x.x.x |            310
                                                      Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.668000 | x.x.x.x |            568
                                                Executing single-partition query on roles [ReadStage-2] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.669000 | x.x.x.x |           1259
                                                             Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-2] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.669000 | x.x.x.x |           1345
                                                              Key cache hit for sstable 2 [ReadStage-2] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.669000 | x.x.x.x |           1475
                Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-2] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.669000 | x.x.x.x |           1569
                                                Merged data from memtables and 1 sstables [ReadStage-2] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.669000 | x.x.x.x |           1768
                                                   Read 1 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-2] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.669000 | x.x.x.x |           1869
                                                Executing single-partition query on roles [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.672000 | x.x.x.x |           4579
                                                             Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.672000 | x.x.x.x |           4701
                                                              Key cache hit for sstable 2 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.672000 | x.x.x.x |           4812
                Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.672000 | x.x.x.x |           4891
                                                Merged data from memtables and 1 sstables [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.672000 | x.x.x.x |           5001
                                                   Read 1 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.673000 | x.x.x.x |           5081
                                                                           Row cache miss [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.674000 | x.x.x.x |           6227
                                                  Executing single-partition query on tb1 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.674000 | x.x.x.x |           6387
                                                             Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.674000 | x.x.x.x |           6445
                Skipped 0/0 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.674001 | x.x.x.x |           6514
                                                                           Caching 3 rows [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.674001 | x.x.x.x |           6647
                                                Merged data from memtables and 0 sstables [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.675000 | x.x.x.x |           7231
                                                   Read 1 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.675000 | x.x.x.x |           7443
                                                                                       Request complete | 2019-01-06 22:21:15.676482 | x.x.x.x |           9482
```

Then the rows are cached, fetching a normal column:
    abc@cqlsh:test> SELECT pk1, ck1, normal_col2 FROM tb1 WHERE pk1=2 and ck1=1;

```
 pk1 | ck1 | normal_col2
-----+-----+-------------
   2 |   1 |           1

(1 rows)

Tracing session: a178ae90-11be-11e9-9cb3-fbffb1c1e13b

 activity                                                                                           | timestamp                  | source       | source_elapsed
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------+----------------
                                                                                 Execute CQL3 query | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.201000 | x.x.x.x |              0
 Parsing SELECT pk1, ck1, normal_col2 FROM tb1 WHERE pk1=2 and ck1=1; [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.202000 | x.x.x.x |            205
                                                  Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.202000 | x.x.x.x |            393
                                            Executing single-partition query on roles [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.202000 | x.x.x.x |            968
                                                         Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.203000 | x.x.x.x |           1413
                                                          Key cache hit for sstable 2 [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.203000 | x.x.x.x |           1564
            Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.203000 | x.x.x.x |           1685
                                            Merged data from memtables and 1 sstables [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.203000 | x.x.x.x |           1841
                                               Read 1 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.203000 | x.x.x.x |           1930
                                            Executing single-partition query on roles [ReadStage-5] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.204000 | x.x.x.x |           2307
                                                         Acquiring sstable references [ReadStage-5] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.204000 | x.x.x.x |           2375
                                                          Key cache hit for sstable 2 [ReadStage-5] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.204000 | x.x.x.x |           2475
            Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones [ReadStage-5] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.204000 | x.x.x.x |           2584
                                            Merged data from memtables and 1 sstables [ReadStage-5] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.204000 | x.x.x.x |           2691
                                               Read 1 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-5] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.204000 | x.x.x.x |           2761
                                                                        Row cache hit [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.205000 | x.x.x.x |           3301
                                               Read 1 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-3] | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.205000 | x.x.x.x |           3489
                                                                                   Request complete | 2019-01-06 22:23:26.204726 | x.x.x.x |           3726
```

Clearly C* will cache the entire row rather than specific columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead of using a large number of columns, instead have a single clustering key that the heavy read columns sort earlier as, then limit the rows_per_partition to just capture those.

You will probably not get a whole lot of benefit vs just caching entire row. Also while the key cache is generally huge for read performance the row cache really only helps in very specific scenarios (and hurts in some) so be sure to benchmark it as the os cache is usually sufficient to keep the important bits in memory.

Comment: The clustering keys serve other business purposes and cannot be changed